# iOS simulator home button double tap (to open task manager) often fails

Tags: ios-simulator, double-click, taskmanager, home-button

Often when I try to open the task manager in an iOS simulator by double tapping the home button it takes a couple of tries. It doesn't matter if you use command+shift+H or the clickable button of the bezel. I had this problem with iOS10 but it seems even worse in iOS11.

Anyone else annoyed by this?

Maybe there is a easier way to open the task manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS simulator: double click home button does not work sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256764/ios-simulator-double-click-home-button-does-not-work-sometimes)

Comment: I have posted an answer on this duplicate question [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983134/3021337](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983134/3021337)

Answer (score 3):

just prass this

**command + shift + H + H**

Xcode 9

Comment: brings up siri in iphone7

Answer (score 1):

Please long press command+shift+h.
Then you will show task manager screen..

Comment: this is the only answer that worked. The "hardware" menu blinks a few times and then sometimes it shows the tasks.